# Is there any faster algorithm to find approx value of log(n) and what will be time complexity of that?

Tags: algorithm, logarithm

Is there any faster algorithm to find approx value of log(n) and what will be time complexity of that ?

I just want approx integer value of log(n) and inbuilt function log(n) in java gives ans with  approximate accuracy in double which is useless for me and it take much time. since log and multiplication are is one of the primary function in my program and but log make my program too much slow.

here some benchmark

> Multiply  took: 466 milliseconds
>
> Logarithm took: 3245 milliseconds

it's approximate 10 time of multiplication.

(Note:-here i used benchmark to just show that it took too much time compare to other primary function of my program and i know it is not possible to compare two different type of function)

so i want to know is there any faster algorithm to find approx value of log(n) and what will be time complexity of that ?

(Note :- algorithm should work for log() with any base)

Comment: A Google search for [fast logarithm approximation] turns up some good possibilities. Have you explored them?

Comment: What algorithm do you mean by 'multiplication'? There are many ways of approximate log (Taylor, Additions with arctan, Hurwitz, ...)

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea if it will actually be faster, but assuming you have an integer `x` and you want its log in base `k`:

```
log_k(x) = log_2(x)/log_2(k)
```

Note that for any `i`, `floor(log_2(i))` is the 'index' of the most significant none zero bit